# Jquery Add/remove Class of seperate div on click

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
 #bottomToolbar #facet-container #tb-facets .info-toolbar #rv-active {
position:relative;
 }

 .tb-1-5 {
display:none;
}


 <div id="bottomToolbar">
    <div id="facet-container">
<ul id="tb-facets">
    <li class="info-toolbar">
    <a id="info-tb-1">Recently Viewed</a>
    <div id="rv-active" class="tb-1-5">Hello World</div></li>
    <li class="info-toolbar">Favorites</li>
    <li class="info-toolbar">Wish List</li>
</ul>
</div>
   </div>


$('#info-tb-1').bind('click', function() {
        $('#rv-active').removeClass('tb-1-5');
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is show a div when I click on an "a" element. I need to change it to remove the display: none;

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very clear on what your question is... the code you have removes the class `tb-1-5` from the element with `id="rv-active"` (and therefore makes it visible).

Comment: I am trying to make the element with id="rv-active" visible, but this script is not working, do you think its a CSS issue?

Comment: It works fine for me... see this fiddle (click "Recently Viewed" and the `div` containing "Hello World" will appear): http://jsfiddle.net/BB7pS/32/ (although as others have noted, using `show()` would be easier).

Comment: I'm putting this script in the head of the document, does that affect the way it is executed? It's not working in my browser [chrome], but it works on the fiddle.

Comment: Try putting your jQuery code inside this: `$(document).ready(function() { ...your code here... });`

Comment: @James or more concisely `$(function () { ...your code here... });`

Comment: @Matt Ball - yes, but I used the longer version so it's clear to the OP what it actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show)?

```
$('#info-tb-1').click(function()
{
    $('#rv-active').show();
});
```

---

Learn to dig through the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/). They will answer 99% of your questions.

Comment: +1 for linking to the docs.  I've come to realize that most people ask questions because they're not familiar with a framework's documentation, and most answers on SO *show* how to do something instead of *teach* how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display something use show();

```
$('#info-tb-1').bind('click', function() {
        $('#rv-active').removeClass('tb-1-5').show();
    });
```

if something is hidden with display:none, using show() display the hidden element

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(elem).hide()` and `$(elem).show()` to add/remove "display:none;"

There is also a `.toggle()` function with an example of what you're trying to do: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

You could've used `document.getElementById('rv-active').style.display="block";` or `$('#rv-active').css("display","block");` and instead styled `#rv-active` directly instead of with all those other divs like this:

```
#bottomToolbar #facet-container #tb-facets .info-toolbar {
  position:relative;
}

 #rv-active {
  position:relative;
  display:none;
}
```

getElementById might not be an ideal tool, but it's useful, especially for things like this.

More about getElementById [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp), and more about the .css() method [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted should work (although many people have already noted, it would be easier to use jQuery's `show` function rather than removing the class).

However, I think your problem lies in the fact that your code is running before the document is fully loaded, and therefore the elements referenced do not exist.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#info-tb-1').bind('click', function() {
        $('#rv-active').show();
    });
});
```